# Matplotlib scatter plot with 2 y-points per x-point

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to create a Scatter plot using Matplotlib.

I have an array of IDs for the x-axis. It looks something like this:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, ...]
#Length = 418
```

For the y-axis, I have an array of tupples. It looks something like this:

```
y = [(1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0), (0, 1), ...]
#Length = 418
```

I would like to plot this in a scatter plot so that for each ID (on the x-axis) it shows a red dot for the first value of the corresponding tupple and a blue dot for the second value of the correspond tuple.

I tried this code:

```
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.xlim(xmin=900, xmax=1300)
plt.ylim(ymin=-1, ymax=2)
plt.yticks(np.arange(2), ('Class 0', 'Class 1'))
plt.xlabel('ID')
plt.ylabel('Class')
plt.show()
```

It shows this result:

[image: my_plot]

**How can I make this plot more clear?**

**Also, when I zoom in, I notice that the points are offset? How can I place them directly above each other?**

[image: zoomed_plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store your data in two lists/tuples instead of one list of two-item tuples, because this is what [plt.plot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) needs as input. The best way would be to reorganize your data like this, but if you are stuck with this list of tuples (or you need this data format for other reasons), you can create lists on the go:

```
plt.plot(x, [i for (i,j) in y], 'ro')
plt.plot(x, [j for (i,j) in y], 'bo')
```

Note that if you want two different data lines with two different colors, you will need two `plt.plot(..)` lines.

To avoid your markers overlapping each other, either you can change their shape or size (or both):

```
plt.plot(x, [i for (i,j) in y], 'rs', markersize = 12 )
plt.plot(x, [j for (i,j) in y], 'bo', markeresize = 8)
```

Comment: This works for me, but how can I put the data points directly above each other? I tried adding `align='center'` but that does not work for `plt.plot`

Comment: On my machine, they are directly above each other. On your screenshot it seems that you have the same values in tuples 900-908. In your tuple 909, there is a blue and a green dot right above each other.

Comment: Oh of course! Stupid of me not to see this.. Is it possible to make one of the 2 dots larger than the other (e.g. the blue dots)? That way, it is possible to see 2 dots on the same place.

Comment: One last question, before I used `plt.scatter`. This does not know the property `markersize`. So I changed it to `plt.plot`. But now, it is connecting the dots with lines. Can I avoid this?

Comment: In my answer, the 'rs' and 'bo' tags define that points should not be represented with lines, but with red squares and blue circles, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to massage your data so that you have flat lists I think.

The most intuitive way to do this I think to define two lists, `y1`, `y2` and loop through your original `y` appending the correct values to them:

```
y1 = []
y2 = []

for i, j in y:
    y1.append(i)
    y2.append(j)
```

Then you can just plot the red and blue scatter graph with two calls to `plt.scatter`

```
plt.scatter(x, y1, c = 'r')
plt.scatter(x, y2, c = 'b')
```

hope that helps!

Comment: This works for me, but how can I put the data points directly above each other? I tried adding `align='center'` but that does not work for `plt.plot`